# Rails Admin throws No route matches error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I have this configuration:

question.rb

```
class Question
    belongs_to :asker
    belongs_to :expert
end
```

user.rb

```
class User
  has_one :asker
  has_one :expert
end
```

I've setup rails_admin and I'm not able to edit any question because of the error.

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError at /question/764/edit
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"rails_admin/main", :id=>nil, :model_name=>"asker"}
```

I've tried adding a show method in the `askers_controller.rb`, but it still doesn't make any difference.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do you have **edit** method in **askers_controller** ?
2. When you try to edit something it should have path like this **edit_admin_news_letter GET    /admin/news_letters/:id/edit**

Comment: Hi, I have added edit method also in askers https://gist.github.com/alagu/60e876fa33cbf830b816d878b9afa71c

Comment: don't you suppose to find that particular record which you want to edit like in

 def edit
    @question = Question.find(764)
end

??

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what you are saying. Should I be doing in askers_controller#edit @question = Question.find(764) ?

Comment: I think the problem is that the id is nil.

Comment: Yes the problem is with the link you are generating to view for **edit page**.
You must check your rake routes and use edit path in link_to tag and with that you can pass id , that id you can get in def edit ... end

suppose your path is edit_path so,
Example: <%= f.link_to 'Edit' , edit_path(@object) %>

This will ask for edit method for the @object

Comment: I don't understand but the error is for the show method and not for the edit method.

Comment: Just to add. This is a rails_admin issue. not a normal rails issue.